# Trying to access a variable inside a loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make 10 diffrent vectors with quite a few rows of data. The code bellow works fine until i want to sort the vector. I know there is something I am missing but I am not good enough to understand what it is. 
Hope some one can help.

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  rnd <- runif(1, 1000, 60000)
  nam <- paste("vec", i, sep = "")
  assign(nam, rweibull(rnd, scale=10, shape = 7))
  nam <- sort(nam)
}
```

Comment: Your code sorts the variable name `nam`, not the vector, which is called `vec1` etc. Perhaps you need to define the vector, sort it, and then give it a name. By the way, it would be normal best practice to store the vectors as a list, rather than as separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to get the value from nam before sort.

```
for(i in 1:10) {
 rnd <- runif(1, 1000, 60000)
 nam <- paste("vec", i, sep = "")
 assign(nam, rweibull(rnd, scale=10, shape = 7))
 assign(nam, sort(get(nam)))
}
```

Comment: That does not work. vec1, vec2, ... are not sorted since the last line is wrong.

Comment: I change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Fix

`nam` is the *name* of the variable, not the variable itself, so the last line needs to be changed to:

```
assign(nam, sort(get(nam)))
```

or else remove the last line and change the second last line to:

```
assign(nam, sort(rweibull(rnd, scale=10, shape = 7)))
```

### Alternative

A better approach might be to create a single list `L` of vectors instead.  Then `L[[i]]` refers to the ith.

```
L <- replicate(10, sort(rweibull(runif(1, 1000, 60000), scale = 10, shape = 7)))
```

### Seed

Note that every time  you run any of the above the random numbers will change so set the seed, e.g.

```
set.seed(123)
```

before you run your code if you want to be able to exactly replicate it when run mulitple times.